# Using ffmpeg to create mp4 file from video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, mp4

I'm reading data from a video stream and using ffmpeg to create a mp4 file. After writing data for a period of time I always get a file with a shorter duration. For example, if I write data for 10 minutes, the final file duration is sometimes 9.8 or 9.6 (the result varies a lot).
Here is how I'm doing:

```
char command[1024];
sprintf(command, "ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel warning -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 15 -s 640x480 -i - -an -vsync vfr -vcodec libx264 -vf \"scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2\" %s", video_filename.c_str());
output_video_pipe = popen(command, "w");
```

Then I write data with:

```
fwrite(video_buffer, 1, video_buffer_size, output_video_pipe);
```

I tried different values for the -vsync parameter but the file is always shorter than it should be. Any tips on how I can make the file have the correct duration?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Small difference makes me think about fps from the stream and different in the file saved - have you checked fps? (frames per second)

Comment: The stream fps varies, normally around 14 and always below 15.

Comment: That's your difference.

Comment: Even if the stream fps varies, can I set ffmpeg to create the file with the same duration as from the moment I open the pipe to the moment I close the pipe?

Comment: Try to vsync or set constant fpses.

Comment: Thanks pbies, I'm using -r 15 to set the constant fps and also tried different values for vsync, but the duration keeps changing.

Comment: It is possible that the input signal is losing some frames - then you can't do anything. I have no further idea.